# How this mixed-character string split on unicode word boundaries

Tags: unicode, rust, split, word-boundary

Consider the string `"abc를"`. According to unicode's [demo implementation of word segmentation](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/breaks.jsp), this string should be split into two words, `"abc"` and `"를"`. However, 3 different Rust implementations of word boundary detection (`regex`, `unic-segment`, `unicode-segmentation`) have *all* disagreed, and grouped that string into one word. Which behavior is correct?

As a follow up, if the grouped behavior is correct, what would be a good way to scan this string for the search term "abc" in a way that still mostly respects word boundaries (for the purpose of checking the validity of string translations). I'd want to match something like `"abc를"` but don't match something like `abcdef`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not so certain that the demo for word segmentation should be taken as the ground truth, even if it is on an official site. For example, it considers `"abc를"` (`"abc\uB97C"`) to be two separate words but considers `"abc를"` (`"abc\u1105\u1173\u11af"`) to be one, even though the former decomposes to the latter.

The idea of a *word boundary* isn't exactly set in stone. Unicode has a [Word Boundary](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundaries) specification which outlines where word-breaks should and should not occurr. However, it has an extensive *notes* section for elaborating on other cases (emphasis mine):

> It is not possible to provide a uniform set of rules that resolves all issues across languages or that handles all ambiguous situations within a given language. The goal for the specification presented in this annex is to provide a workable default; tailored implementations can be more sophisticated.
>
> For Thai, Lao, Khmer, Myanmar, and other scripts that do not typically use spaces between words, a good implementation should not depend on the default word boundary specification. It should use a more sophisticated mechanism, as is also required for line breaking. Ideographic scripts such as Japanese and Chinese are even more complex. Where **Hangul** text is written without spaces, the same applies. However, in the absence of a more sophisticated mechanism, the rules specified in this annex supply a well-defined default.
>
> ...

My understanding is that the crates you list are following the spec without further contextual analysis. Why the demo disagrees I cannot say, but it may be an attempt to implement one of these edge cases.

---

To address your specific problem, I'd suggest using [`Regex`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.4.3/regex/struct.Regex.html) with `\b` for matching a word boundary. This unfortunately follows the same unicode rules and will not consider `"를"` to be a new word. However, this regex implementation offers an [escape hatch](https://docs.rs/regex/1.4.3/regex/#opt-out-of-unicode-support) to fallback to ascii behaviour. Simply use `(?-u:\b)` to match a non-unicode boundary:

```
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let pattern = Regex::new("(?-u:\\b)abc(?-u:\\b)").unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", pattern.find("some abcdef abc를 sentence"));
}
```

You can run it for yourself on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cad5db8ba771cdd5196e1ede557303db) to test your cases and see if this works for you.